# In <template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="items">, item displays as [object Object]

Tags: angularjs, angular

If I interpolate a string variable in a repeated `<li>` it shows up correctly, but if I put it in a `<template><li>` it shows up as [object Object]. Why is that? I've seen a few evolutions of the `<template>` syntax but none seems to work.

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kRzCSm?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `#item` then `item` will refer to TemplateRef. You need to use `let-item` like this:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
  <li>{{item}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. I never would have guessed that let-item is a thing you're supposed to change to let-myvariable or whatnot. It looks to me like a keyword sitting there right next to the ngFor keyword.

Comment: is let-item from an older version of angular2?  i can't find any documentation on it in the current docs.

Comment: Really close to what I'm looking for, however, how would this work if items was an ObservableArray?